Display a graph as boxes that fit a single box?
let's say I have a graph like
graph = [
    {
        id: 0,
        quantity: 30,
        next: [2]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        quantity: 110,
        next: [3, 4]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        quantity: 30,
        next: [6]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        quantity: 90,
        next: [5]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        quantity: 20,
        next: [6]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        quantity: 90,
        next: [7]
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        quantity: 50,
        next: [7]
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        quantity: 140,
        next: []
    },
]

I know the starting nodes (0&1) and the quantity is the percentage of the box it should take. I'd like to display it like this

but each box should stretch to make sure they all fit the whole box so if I change my graph to
graph = [
    {
        id: 0,
        quantity: 30,
        next: [2]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        quantity: 110,
        next: [3, 4]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        quantity: 30,
        next: [6]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        quantity: 90,
        next: [5]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        quantity: 20,
        next: [6]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        quantity: 90,
        next: [6]
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        quantity: 140,
        next: []
    }
]

I'd like it to look like this instead

I'd like to ask you:
Do you know any js library (preferably a react one) that does it out of the box ?
